# Scrolling child element inside parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent element with two children. One child is a dynamic ul where admins will add and remove menu links as they please. The second child is a scrolling box with feeds inside. You can image it as a Twitter feed since that's what it reminds me of.

The problem I'm having is that since I cannot define the height of the first child, I can't get the second child to act right. I don't want scrollbars on the parent, but would like to have a y scrollbar on the second child once it reaches the end of the parent's bottom axis. So far I can get the parent to have a scroll bar and cut off the second child at the bottom access or I can get the second child to overflow completely out of the parent.

Thanks.

```
<style>
.inline-block { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
.nowrap { white-space: nowrap; }
#sidebar { width: 256px; padding: 11px 10px 10px; margin: 0 20px 0 0; border: 2px solid #969696; background: #e8e8e8; height: 636px; }
#ad_list { width: 244px; border: 1px solid #969696; padding: 6px 5px 5px; margin: 20px 0 0; overflow: auto; }
.ad_link { white-space: normal; margin-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #969696; padding-bottom: 10px; }
</style>

<aside id="sidebar" class="inline-block">
    <ul id="sidebar_links">
        <li class="link_button">Item 1</li>
        <li class="link_button">Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="ad_list">
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
        <li class="ad_link"><a href="/">This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy. This is some ad copy.</a></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding a height to your `#ad_list` should do the trick.

```
#ad_list { height:500px; }
```

Comment: That ignores the factor of the dynamic first child. Once an admin adds a menu item, as seen in this fiddle jsfiddle.net/D5kYS/3, the bottom child will overflow the parent again.

Comment: Well, if your #sidebar div must have a fixed height, than I don't know any other way than using JavaScript/jQuery.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ufYHj/

Comment: I'll take it. Normally I try to exhaust all non-javascript solutions first but in this case I can a) probably say there is no css way and b) control all the admins and tell them not to do something stupid like turn off javascript.

Comment: Alternatively I did explore using an iframe and moving ad_list to it's own HTML document. It succeed on a few fronts, namely the scrollbox inside the parent and added the extra benefit of making it easier to edit the ad_list contents, but I didn't get around to the auto-sizing yet. But now that I have this I have just gone back tot he way it was here and it's working perfectly. Thanks.